# Dapper: Using <T> to execute multiple queries from different resources

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

Ok so I have ZERO idea how to word it in a title so I will explain what I am looking to achieve here.

I have a .cs file that houses a connection code utilizing dapper listed below.

```
namespace DBConnector
{

    public static class Helper
    {

        public static string CnnVal(string name)
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
        }

    }

    public class DataAccess<T>
    {
        public List<T> GetInfo(string query, object parameters = null)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("ProxyRPDB")))
            {
                return connection.Query<T>(string, object);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve, is have a query executed from a DIFFERENT .cs file through the above code. BUT! I am trying to make it so that above code accepts query executions from multiple .cs files that all need different data from different tables. I have tried forever to find the information... so this is truly last resort. I am using Dapper for .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: hi, was there a compiler error?

Comment: I havent even gotten to that phase yet because I have no idea how to complete the code. The only errors I do have at the moment are inside the connection.Query<T>(string, object); 

Stating they are invalid terms. But Idk what to actually put there.

Comment: did you mean `connection.Query<T>(query, parameters);`?

Comment: Incase it is unclear what I am trying to achieve (because I feel like im not explaing it correctly). Ill provide an example.

I have the above DataAccess.cs which houses my connection string and the connection.Query.

I have 2 other .cs scripts that I want to be able to send a query THROUGH this scripts connection.Query so I do not have to constantly rewrite them for other scripts. Instead opting to use arguments (if you will) to provide the information inside the Query<T>() so that way I can have them get the info they need from the table they need.

Comment: @ScottyD0nt , changing it to that invokes and error.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: In addition to changing `object` to `parameters`, also change the return type from `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: `connection.Query<T>(string, object);` isn't valid C#.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn ok so that removed all the errors! Now how do I get another script in a different .cs to send a query through that piece of code?

Comment: I've made a few other changes as well in my answer.

Comment: @TrashaPanda - cs files aren't scripts. They are compiled code that forms part of a system. Scripts are typically interpreted code that acts upon a system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to fix the basic syntax errors in the `GetInfo()` method:

```
public static class DataAccess
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetInfo<T>(string query, object parameters = null)
    {
        using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Helper.CnnVal("ProxyRPDB")))
        {
            return connection.Query<T>(query, parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, assuming you have the proper reference and using directives in other *.cs files, you can do things like this inside those files:

```
var results = DataAccess.GetInfo<MyTableType>("SELECT * FROM [MyTable]");
foreach(var record in results)
{
  //...
}
```

Dapper will now try to map the query results to instances of the `MyTableType` class, so make sure you've created such a class.

Note this works with IEnumerable instead of List. If you really need a List (hint: you usually don't, and IEnumerable can perform much better) you can always put a `.ToList()` at the end of the function call:

```
var results = DataAccess.GetInfo<MyTableType>("SELECT * FROM [MyTable]").ToList();
```

Comment: So this seems to solve my issue. Just 1 question. 

Does the table need to exist within the .cs that I am trying call with 
"var results = DataAccess.GetInfo<MyTableType>("SELECT * FROM [MyTable]");"
or can I have them all stored in a single .cs.

Comment: Totally forgot to change and fix the other syntax errors. All errors are gone and everything LOOKS to be functional.

Comment: Tables don't exist within *.cs files. The class definition needs to exist somewhere within your project, but that's all.

Comment: So how do I reference a class definition located in another .cs inside the < "   " >

Comment: Either fully-qualify the class name (including the namespace) or add a `using` directive for the namespace at the top of the file.